# Changing a remote website's JavaScript locally with a FireFox Extension?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

I am trying to write a browser extension to add some functionality and reformat some data on a third-party website.

I installed Firefox Developer Edition.  I then created a simple Add-on extension based on [Beastify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Your_second_WebExtension).

I wrote a simple script to monitor when the innerHTML of a span element changes and then do some processing.

This code works, but it is not the way I want to do things:

```
function fixformat(){
    var value = document.getElementById("value");

    var valueFloat = parseFloat(value.innerHTML);

    if (valueFloat < 1000) valueFloat += 1000;

    value.innerHTML = valueFloat;
}
setInterval(fixformat, 100);
```

On the remote server it is updating the value in real-time with the following code:

```
totValue += _currentValue;
value = document.getElementById("value");
value.innerHTML = totValue;
```

But I would like to replace this line:

```
value.innerHTML = totValue;
```

With this:

```
value.innerHTML = totValue + 1000;
```

This code is buried in a huge remote javascript file, one of about two dozen javascripts that get loaded when I browse their website.  This javascript file has about 4000 lines of code. It executes like every 1-15 seconds when new information is available.

Is there some way to programatically hook into that remote javascript file?  Do some kind of simple search and replace on that line of code, which will let everything else execute normally?

Comment: Maybe you can create a copy of the script and make the modifications you require. Then when the page loads, remove the original script tag and add your modified script.

Comment: Well that would probably work but it seems like a maintenance nightmare whenever the third party site updates something.  I'm planning on writing a lot of little UI hacks and it would be much better to search and replace a line of code here and there than to keep local copies of thousands of lines of code.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion though, I'm looking into [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38071258/changing-a-remote-websites-javascript-locally-with-a-webextension)

Answer (score 3):

You would use the `beforescriptexecute` event listener and change the `.textContent` of the script.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/beforescriptexecute

Here is an example:

```
document.addEventListener("beforescriptexecute", function(e) {
        src = e.target.src;
        content = e.target.text;

        if (src.search("i18n.js") > -1) {
            // Stop original script
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
            window.jQuery(e.target).remove();

            var script = document.createElement('script');

            script.textContent = 'script you want';

            (document.head || document.documentElement).appendChild(script);
            script.onload = function() {
                this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm this does not work with WebExtension, but I'm going to try an xpi-style extension.  It seems that adblock plus is able to remove javascripts from executing so I just need a way to replace them.  Going to study the ABP source code.

Comment: Thanks for your help, your idea worked, I just couldn't figure out how to do it in a browser extension but I found a way to do it with GreaseMonkey :)

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I gave up on the browser extension idea for now given that I can do what I desire with a [Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) script. Here is the script I wrote that worked for creating a "hook" into the remote JavaScript to replace one line of code:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        test load
// @namespace   testing
// @description testing
// @include     https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/
// @version     1
// @grant       none
// @run-at document-start
// ==/UserScript==
document.addEventListener("beforescriptexecute", function(e) {
    src = e.target.src;
    content = e.target.text;
    console.log("src: " + src);
    if (src.search("script.js") > -1) {
        var newContent = "";
        $.ajax({
            async: false,
            type: 'GET',
            url: '/script.js',
            success: function(data) { //inject code via search and replace
                newContent=data.replace('totValue += value;', 'totValue += value + 1000;');
            }
        });
        // Stop original script
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        window.jQuery(e.target).remove();
        var script = document.createElement('script');
        script.textContent = newContent;
        (document.head || document.documentElement).appendChild(script);
        script.onload = function() {
            this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Very cool thanks for sharing. You should try with WebExtension. You should set your content script to load in at start of page, and then do it there. It should work.

Comment: I tried it and couldn't figure it out.  I decided though that I'm going in a different direction, now that I've discovered [CefSharp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38096349/modifying-remote-javascripts-as-they-load-with-cefsharp).  Will be posting my solution there once I figure it out.

Comment: Thank you. I have deleted my comment as it is no longer relevant. A few additional things: A) Only the author of the post on which comments are being made will be notified of your comment unless you include their name such as: `@Makyen` in your comment. B) Given that this is the solution you used as the answer to your question you should accept this answer. C) I removed the white space lines in your code to make it display without the need to scroll the code. When possible, code is much more understandable if it can be displayed all at one time without needing vertical or horizontal scrolling.

Comment: Alright @Makyen thanks for letting me know.  It says I have to wait a few more hours to mark the solution as accepted.

Comment: you've used .search which makes the . a wildcard