# Modifying remote JavaScripts as they load with CefSharp version 79?

Tags: cefsharp

I am using Cefsharp.Winform version 79 (the latest version). 
After load a web page, I want to modify the loaded content of a js file.
I found some suggestions in the answer to question [Modifying remote JavaScripts as they load with CefSharp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38096349/modifying-remote-javascripts-as-they-load-with-cefsharp) 
but it was 3 years ago and they used old version of cefsharp.
How do I perform this using cefsharp version 79?
Please help me.

Comment: See https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#response-filtering the IResponseFilter API itself hasn't changed,  just some of the methods were moved around when CEF added support for the chromium network service.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I will implement this one.